# How to search virtual machine names using only a part of them in Ansible VMware?

Tags: ansible, yaml, vmware

I'm trying to search VM in **VMware** using *ansible plugins* like `vmware_vm_info` in order to execute snapshots later. Seems that `vm_name` is a case sensitive parameter in all of the plugins of **VMware** using ansible.

I tried to send wildcards inside a string variable without success. Anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: Best woud be that you give us an relevant enough example of structure of the data produced by `vmware_vm_info` (e.g. producing in your question what a debug` on the data gives), then there are better chances we could help you in here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in [the documentation of the module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/vmware_vm_info_module.html), it will produce a result looking like this:

```json
[
   {
      "attributes":{
         "job":"backup-prepare"
      },
      "cluster":"None",
      "datacenter":"Datacenter-1",
      "esxi_hostname":"10.76.33.226",
      "folder":"/Datacenter-1/vm",
      "guest_fullname":"Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)",
      "guest_name":"ubuntu_t",
      "ip_address":"",
      "mac_address":[
         "00:50:56:87:a5:9a"
      ],
      "moid":"vm-24",
      "power_state":"poweredOff",
      "tags":[
         {
            "category_id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:b316cc45-f1a9-4277-811d-56c7e7975203:GLOBAL",
            "category_name":"cat_0001",
            "description":"",
            "id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:43737ec0-b832-4abf-abb1-fd2448ce3b26:GLOBAL",
            "name":"tag_0001"
         }
      ],
      "uuid":"4207072c-edd8-3bd5-64dc-903fd3a0db04",
      "vm_network":{
         "00:50:56:87:a5:9a":{
            "ipv4":[
               "10.76.33.228"
            ],
            "ipv6":[
               
            ]
         }
      }
   }
]
```

```
*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/vmware_vm_info_module.html#return-values*
```

As I don't see any `vm_name` here, I am going to assume that you meant `guest_name`, but the idea behind this playbook will be applicable to any attribute that you find fit.

What you can do to extract values of a list of dictionaries as a simple list is to use the Jinja filter [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map).

Here would be an example playbook based on the data documented for this module, where I added a second fake VM, for the sake of demonstrating result with more than one item in the list:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ virtual_machines | map(attribute='guest_name') | list }}"
      vars:
        virtual_machines: [
          {
              "attributes":{
                "job":"backup-prepare"
              },
              "cluster":"None",
              "datacenter":"Datacenter-1",
              "esxi_hostname":"10.76.33.226",
              "folder":"/Datacenter-1/vm",
              "guest_fullname":"Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)",
              "guest_name":"ubuntu_t",
              "ip_address":"",
              "mac_address":[
                "00:50:56:87:a5:9a"
              ],
              "moid":"vm-24",
              "power_state":"poweredOff",
              "tags":[
                {
                    "category_id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:b316cc45-f1a9-4277-811d-56c7e7975203:GLOBAL",
                    "category_name":"cat_0001",
                    "description":"",
                    "id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:43737ec0-b832-4abf-abb1-fd2448ce3b26:GLOBAL",
                    "name":"tag_0001"
                }
              ],
              "uuid":"4207072c-edd8-3bd5-64dc-903fd3a0db04",
              "vm_network":{
                "00:50:56:87:a5:9a":{
                    "ipv4":[
                      "10.76.33.228"
                    ],
                    "ipv6":[
                      
                    ]
                }
              }
          },
          {
              "attributes":{
                "job":"backup-prepare"
              },
              "cluster":"None",
              "datacenter":"Datacenter-1",
              "esxi_hostname":"10.76.33.226",
              "folder":"/Datacenter-1/vm",
              "guest_fullname":"Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)",
              "guest_name":"ubuntu_t_2",
              "ip_address":"",
              "mac_address":[
                "00:50:56:87:a5:9a"
              ],
              "moid":"vm-24",
              "power_state":"poweredOff",
              "tags":[
                {
                    "category_id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:b316cc45-f1a9-4277-811d-56c7e7975203:GLOBAL",
                    "category_name":"cat_0001",
                    "description":"",
                    "id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:43737ec0-b832-4abf-abb1-fd2448ce3b26:GLOBAL",
                    "name":"tag_0001"
                }
              ],
              "uuid":"4207072c-edd8-3bd5-64dc-903fd3a0db04",
              "vm_network":{
                "00:50:56:87:a5:9a":{
                    "ipv4":[
                      "10.76.33.228"
                    ],
                    "ipv6":[
                      
                    ]
                }
              }
          }
        ]
```

And here would be the recap of it:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "ubuntu_t",
        "ubuntu_t_2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```